# Как отследить, что пользователь перестал выполнять задачу?

Tags: java, spring, сессия, redis, spring-session

Приложение на стеке `Spring Boot`, для хранения сессий используется `Spring Session` и `Redis`.

Есть пользователь. Он может начать проходить тест. Тест проходится в постоянном взаимодействии с сервером: пользователь получает вопрос, отправляет на сервер ответ и получает следующий вопрос. Когда тест кончится, надо записать результаты в БД. Пока тест не завершён, ответы пользователя должны храниться в сессии *(сессия, напоминаю, хранится в `Redis`)*.

Пользователь может прервать тест, в частности:

- Закрыть вкладку
- Перейти по другому адресу со страницы теста
- Нажать кнопку "Отменить тест"
- Перезагрузить страницу

В этих случаях надо обнулять уже данные пользователем ответы, то есть откатывать тест. Для решения этой задачи мне на ум приходит только пингование, но и его с трудом понимаю, как его реализовать. Сессии, напоминаю, хранятся не в памяти, а в `Redis`.

Вопрос: как сделать сброс теста?

Comment: Можно проверять сессии на предмет их действительности и закрывать на сервере, если они устарели.

Comment: @OlegMarchenko это немного другое. Конечно, если сессия закрывается, то тест сбрасывается. Но мне надо сбрасывать тест независимо от сессии. То есть сессия может быть всё ещё открыта, а вот тест надо сбросить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось довольно простое.

Когда тест создаётся, я генерирую уникальный ключ, по которому данные теста сохраняются в `Redis`. Этот же ключ я возвращаю клиенту, где он сохраняется в `state`. Когда клиент хочет дать ответ на следующий вопрос, то помимо самого ответа на сервер отсылается ещё и ключ из `state`. `Redis` при помощи этого ключа пытается найти запись с данными теста и, если запись отсутствует, возвращает ошибку.

После каждого запроса ключ обновляется *(это нужно, чтобы сбрасывать TTL записи в `Redis`)*. Если пользователь закрывает вкладку / обновляет её, то `state` затирается, ключ исчезает, а с ним клиент теряет доступ к тесту. Поэтому пользователь вынужден начинать тест с самого начала.